# Calculate length of array inside procedure using offset passed through parameter, Assembly language x8086

Tags: assembly, offset, x86-16, procedure, masm

So i am trying to get the length of array by using the offset in the parameter but it is only returning lenthof offset. Is there any way I can do this?
`

```
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc
multiply proto,arr:ptr dword
.data
array dword 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
num dword 3
.code
main PROC
    invoke multiply,addr array
    exit
main ENDP

multiply proc,arr:ptr dword
    mov ecx,lengthof arr
    mov eax, ecx
    call writedec


    ret
multiply endp

END main
```

`

Comment: No, a pointer does not have the array size associated with it. Pass the size separately or use a terminator or a length prefix.

Comment: `lengthof arr` is just like the `sizeof` operator in C; it's a compile-time constant that you don't have to use a `#define` on. You can't use it dynamically like you're trying to do there.

Answer (score 2):

The reason your `mulitply proc` doesn't work is that `lengthof` is strictly a compile-time constant. The below code is perfectly fine:

```
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc
multiply proto,arr:ptr dword
.data
array dword 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
num dword 3
.code
main PROC
    mov ecx,lengthof array ;assembler replaces this with 40 (byte count of your array)
    mov eax, ecx
    call writedec
    exit
main ENDP
END main
```

This doesn't work, however, if you have a function that is trying to use a variable as you have done. There's no way to tell MASM that in this function your input is an array of dwords and not just a single dword. This is because the CPU doesn't have this information at runtime. A pointer doesn't actually carry any information about the length of an array it's pointing to, just like in C with `void foo(int *arr)`.  It's a pointer, not truly an array.

```
multiply proc,arr:ptr dword
    mov ecx,lengthof arr  ;this just returns a constant value regardless of input.
    mov eax, ecx
    call writedec


    ret
multiply endp
```

In order to do what you want, you need to pass the length of the array as an extra parameter. I'm not entirely familiar with the MASM syntax for `proc` but I think you can figure it out. If you do something like this:

```
invoke multiply, addr array, lengthof array
```

and write your `proc` accordingly, you should get the desired result.